# Error when Looping and Inserting XML Data into MS SQL Server Tables with XQuery Namespace

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, xml-parsing, namespaces, xquery

**Description:**
I am currently working on a task that involves parsing an XML document and inserting its data into SQL Server tables. The XML document contains invoice information, and I need to loop through each invoice and insert the data into two tables: EDIInboundInvoiceHeader and EDIInboundInvoiceLineItems. However, I encountered an issue with the XQuery namespace declaration while attempting to insert the data.
**Problem:**
When executing the stored procedure to insert the XML data into the tables, I encounter the following error:

Msg 2229, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertEDIInboundInvoiceNew, Line 60 [Batch Start Line 8]
XQuery [query()]: The name "ns0" does not denote a namespace.

Stored procedure is given below

```
USE [IntegrationStaging]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertEDIInboundInvoiceNew]    Script Date: 8/9/2023 11:15:34 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertEDIInboundInvoiceNew]
    @InvoiceStatus VARCHAR(50),
    @ProcessStatus VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @IntegrationProcess VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @InvoiceXML XML,
    @StatusMessage VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    

        DECLARE @InvoiceID VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @BusinessUnit VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @InvoiceNumber VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @InvoiceAmount VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @InvoiceDate DATE
        DECLARE @SupplierName VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @SupplierNumber VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @SupplierSite VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @InvoiceCurrency VARCHAR(10)
        DECLARE @PaymentCurrency VARCHAR(10)
        DECLARE @ImportSet VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @InvoiceType VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @LegalEntity VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @PaymentTerm VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @TermsDate DATE
        DECLARE @GoodsReceivedDate DATE
        DECLARE @InvoiceReceiveDate DATE
        DECLARE @AccountingDate DATE
        DECLARE @PaymentMethod VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @PayGroup VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @LiabilityDistribution VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @CreationDate DATETIME
        DECLARE @Source VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @IntegrationName VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @Status VARCHAR(50)

        DECLARE @LineNumber INT
        DECLARE @LineType VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @Amount VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @InvoiceQuantity INT
        DECLARE @UnitPrice VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @UOM VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @Description VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @PONumber VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @DistributionCombination VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @DistributionSet VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @TaxControlAmount VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @TaxRegimeCode VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @Tax VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @TaxStatusCode VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @TaxJurisdictionCode VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @TaxRateCode VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @TaxRate VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @WithholdingTaxGroup VARCHAR(50)
                -- Iterate through each invoice in the XML
        DECLARE @InvoiceNodes XML
        
        SET @InvoiceNodes = @InvoiceXML.query('/ns0:InvoiceCanonical')

        DECLARE @InvoiceCount INT
        
        SELECT @InvoiceCount = @InvoiceNodes.value('count(/ns0:InvoiceCanonical)', 'INT')

        DECLARE @CurrentInvoice INT = 1

        WHILE @CurrentInvoice <= @InvoiceCount
        BEGIN
        
            SELECT
                @InvoiceID = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:InvoiceID)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @BusinessUnit = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:BusinessUnit)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @InvoiceNumber = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:InvoiceNumber)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @InvoiceAmount = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:InvoiceAmount)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                @InvoiceDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:InvoiceDate)[1]', 'DATE'),
                @SupplierName = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:SupplierName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                @SupplierNumber = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:SupplierNumber)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @SupplierSite = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:SupplierSite)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @InvoiceCurrency = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:InvoiceCurrency)[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'),
                @PaymentCurrency = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:PaymentCurrency)[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'),
                @ImportSet = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:ImportSet)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @InvoiceType = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:InvoiceType)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @LegalEntity = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:LegalEntity)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @PaymentTerm = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:PaymentTerm)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @TermsDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:TermsDate)[1]', 'DATE'),
                @GoodsReceivedDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:GoodsReceivedDate)[1]', 'DATE'),
                @InvoiceReceiveDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:InvoiceReceiveDate)[1]', 'DATE'),
                @AccountingDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:AccountingDate)[1]', 'DATE'),
                @PaymentMethod = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:PaymentMethod)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @PayGroup = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:PayGroup)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @LiabilityDistribution = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:LiabilityDistribution)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @CreationDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:CreationDate)[1]', 'DATETIME'),
                @Source = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:Source)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @IntegrationName = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:IntegrationName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @Status = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:Status)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
            FROM @InvoiceXML.nodes('/ns0:InvoiceCanonical[' + CAST(@CurrentInvoice AS VARCHAR) + ']/ns0:Header') AS InvoiceHeader(InvoiceHeader)

            -- Insert data into EDIInboundInvoiceHeader
            INSERT INTO EDIInboundInvoiceHeader (
                InvoiceStatus, ProcessStatus, IntegrationProcess, InvoiceID, BusinessUnit, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceAmount, InvoiceDate,
                SupplierName, SupplierNumber, SupplierSite, InvoiceCurrency,
                PaymentCurrency, ImportSet, InvoiceType, LegalEntity,
                CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber, PaymentTerm, TermsDate,
                GoodsReceivedDate, InvoiceReceiveDate, AccountingDate,
                PaymentMethod, PayGroup, LiabilityDistribution, CreationDate,
                Source, IntegrationName, Status
            )
            VALUES (
                @InvoiceStatus, @ProcessStatus, @IntegrationProcess, @InvoiceID, @BusinessUnit, @InvoiceNumber, @InvoiceAmount, @InvoiceDate,
                @SupplierName, @SupplierNumber, @SupplierSite, @InvoiceCurrency,
                @PaymentCurrency, @ImportSet, @InvoiceType, @LegalEntity,
                @CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber, @PaymentTerm, @TermsDate,
                @GoodsReceivedDate, @InvoiceReceiveDate, @AccountingDate,
                @PaymentMethod, @PayGroup, @LiabilityDistribution, @CreationDate,
                @Source, @IntegrationName, @Status
            )

            DECLARE @InvoiceHeaderID INT
            SET @InvoiceHeaderID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

            -- Insert data into EDIInboundInvoiceLineItems
            INSERT INTO EDIInboundInvoiceLineItems (InvoiceHeaderID, LineNumber, LineType, Amount, InvoiceQuantity, UnitPrice, UOM, Description, PONumber, DistributionCombination, DistributionSet, AccountingDate, TaxControlAmount, TaxRegimeCode, Tax, TaxStatusCode, TaxJurisdictionCode, TaxRateCode, TaxRate, WithholdingTaxGroup)
            SELECT
                @InvoiceHeaderID,
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:LineNumber)[1]', 'INT'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:LineType)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                -- ... other attribute extractions ...
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:Amount)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:InvoiceQuantity)[1]', 'INT'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:UnitPrice)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:UOM)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:Description)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:PONumber)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:DistributionCombination)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:DistributionSet)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:AccountingDate)[1]', 'DATE'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:TaxControlAmount)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:TaxRegimeCode)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:Tax)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:TaxStatusCode)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:TaxJurisdictionCode)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:TaxRateCode)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:TaxRate)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:WithholdingTaxGroup)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
            FROM @InvoiceXML.nodes('/ns0:InvoiceCanonical[' + CAST(@CurrentInvoice AS VARCHAR) + ']/ns0:Detail') AS InvoiceItem(InvoiceItem)

            SET @CurrentInvoice = @CurrentInvoice + 1
        END

        SET @StatusMessage = 'Success' -- Output message on success
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @StatusMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() -- Return error message on failure
    END CATCH
END
```

XML input is given below

```
<ns0:InvoiceCanonical xmlns:ns0="namespace_URL">
  <Header xmlns:ns0="namespace_URL">
    <InvoiceID>INV0001</InvoiceID>
    <BusinessUnit>BU123</BusinessUnit>
    <InvoiceNumber>INV123456</InvoiceNumber>
    <InvoiceAmount>1500.00</InvoiceAmount>
    <InvoiceDate>2023-08-01</InvoiceDate>
    <SupplierName>ABC Supplier</SupplierName>
    <SupplierNumber>SUP001</SupplierNumber>
    <SupplierSite>Main Site</SupplierSite>
    <InvoiceCurrency>USD</InvoiceCurrency>
    <PaymentCurrency>USD</PaymentCurrency>
    <ImportSet>ImportSet_123</ImportSet>
    <InvoiceType>Regular</InvoiceType>
    <LegalEntity>LE001</LegalEntity>
    <CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber>1234567890</CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber>
    <PaymentTerm>Net 30</PaymentTerm>
    <TermsDate>2023-09-01</TermsDate>
    <GoodsReceivedDate>2023-07-25</GoodsReceivedDate>
    <InvoiceReceiveDate>2023-08-02</InvoiceReceiveDate>
    <AccountingDate>2023-08-02</AccountingDate>
    <PaymentMethod>Bank Transfer</PaymentMethod>
    <PayGroup>PG001</PayGroup>
    <LiabilityDistribution>LD001</LiabilityDistribution>
    <CreationDate>2023-08-01T08:00:00</CreationDate>
    <Source>System A</Source>
    <IntegrationName>Integration_ABC</IntegrationName>
    <Status>Approved</Status>
  </Header>
  <Detail xmlns:ns0="namespace_URL">
    <InvoiceID>INV0001</InvoiceID>
    <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
    <LineType>Item</LineType>
    <Amount>500.00</Amount>
    <InvoiceQuantity>10</InvoiceQuantity>
    <UnitPrice>50.00</UnitPrice>
    <UOM>EA</UOM>
    <Description>Product A</Description>
    <PONumber>PO1234</PONumber>
    <DistributionCombination>DC123</DistributionCombination>
    <DistributionSet>DS001</DistributionSet>
    <AccountingDate>2023-08-02</AccountingDate>
    <TaxControlAmount>50.00</TaxControlAmount>
    <TaxRegimeCode>TAXREG001</TaxRegimeCode>
    <Tax>10.00</Tax>
    <TaxStatusCode>TAXSTAT001</TaxStatusCode>
    <TaxJurisdictionCodeTaxJurisdictionCode>TAXJUR001</TaxJurisdictionCodeTaxJurisdictionCode>
    <TaxRateCode>TAXRATE001</TaxRateCode>
    <TaxRate>10%</TaxRate>
    <WithholdingTaxGroup>WTG001</WithholdingTaxGroup>
  </Detail>
  <Detail xmlns:ns0="namespace_URL">
    <InvoiceID>INV0001</InvoiceID>
    <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
    <LineType>Item</LineType>
    <Amount>800.00</Amount>
    <InvoiceQuantity>5</InvoiceQuantity>
    <UnitPrice>160.00</UnitPrice>
    <UOM>EA</UOM>
    <Description>Product B</Description>
    <PONumber>PO5678</PONumber>
    <DistributionCombination>DC456</DistributionCombination>
    <DistributionSet>DS002</DistributionSet>
    <AccountingDate>2023-08-03</AccountingDate>
    <TaxControlAmount>80.00</TaxControlAmount>
    <TaxRegimeCode>TAXREG002</TaxRegimeCode>
    <Tax>16.00</Tax>
    <TaxStatusCode>TAXSTAT002</TaxStatusCode>
    <TaxJurisdictionCodeTaxJurisdictionCode>TAXJUR002</TaxJurisdictionCodeTaxJurisdictionCode>
    <TaxRateCode>TAXRATE002</TaxRateCode>
    <TaxRate>20%</TaxRate>
    <WithholdingTaxGroup>WTG002</WithholdingTaxGroup>
  </Detail>
  <Detail xmlns:ns0="namespace_URL">
    <InvoiceID>INV0001</InvoiceID>
    <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
    <LineType>Item</LineType>
    <Amount>300.00</Amount>
    <InvoiceQuantity>3</InvoiceQuantity>
    <UnitPrice>100.00</UnitPrice>
    <UOM>EA</UOM>
    <Description>Product C</Description>
    <PONumber>PO9090</PONumber>
    <DistributionCombination>DC789</DistributionCombination>
    <DistributionSet>DS003</DistributionSet>
    <AccountingDate>2023-08-03</AccountingDate>
    <TaxControlAmount>30.00</TaxControlAmount>
    <TaxRegimeCode>TAXREG003</TaxRegimeCode>
    <Tax>9.00</Tax>
    <TaxStatusCode>TAXSTAT003</TaxStatusCode>
    <TaxJurisdictionCodeTaxJurisdictionCode>TAXJUR003</TaxJurisdictionCodeTaxJurisdictionCode>
    <TaxRateCode>TAXRATE003</TaxRateCode>
    <TaxRate>9%</TaxRate>
    <WithholdingTaxGroup>WTG003</WithholdingTaxGroup>
  </Detail>
</ns0:InvoiceCanonical>
<ns0:InvoiceCanonical xmlns:ns0="namespace_URL">
  <Header xmlns:ns0="http://Invoice.Common.Schemas.InvoiceCanonical">
    <InvoiceID>INV0002</InvoiceID>
    <BusinessUnit>BU456</BusinessUnit>
    <InvoiceNumber>INV789012</InvoiceNumber>
    <InvoiceAmount>2500.00</InvoiceAmount>
    <InvoiceDate>2023-08-05</InvoiceDate>
    <SupplierName>XYZ Suppliers</SupplierName>
    <SupplierNumber>SUP002</SupplierNumber>
    <SupplierSite>Secondary Site</SupplierSite>
    <InvoiceCurrency>EUR</InvoiceCurrency>
    <PaymentCurrency>EUR</PaymentCurrency>
    <ImportSet>ImportSet_456</ImportSet>
    <InvoiceType>Special</InvoiceType>
    <LegalEntity>LE002</LegalEntity>
    <CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber>9876543210</CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber>
    <PaymentTerm>Net 45</PaymentTerm>
    <TermsDate>2023-09-15</TermsDate>
    <GoodsReceivedDate>2023-08-01</GoodsReceivedDate>
    <InvoiceReceiveDate>2023-08-06</InvoiceReceiveDate>
    <AccountingDate>2023-08-06</AccountingDate>
    <PaymentMethod>Credit Card</PaymentMethod>
    <PayGroup>PG002</PayGroup>
    <LiabilityDistribution>LD002</LiabilityDistribution>
    <CreationDate>2023-08-05T09:30:00</CreationDate>
    <Source>System B</Source>
    <IntegrationName>Integration_XYZ</IntegrationName>
    <Status>Pending Approval</Status>
  </Header>
  <Detail xmlns:ns0="namespace_URL">
    <InvoiceID>INV0002</InvoiceID>
    <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
    <LineType>Item</LineType>
    <Amount>800.00</Amount>
    <InvoiceQuantity>8</InvoiceQuantity>
    <UnitPrice>100.00</UnitPrice>
    <UOM>EA</UOM>
    <Description>Product X</Description>
    <PONumber>PO9876</PONumber>
    <DistributionCombination>DC987</DistributionCombination>
    <DistributionSet>DS004</DistributionSet>
    <AccountingDate>2023-08-06</AccountingDate>
    <TaxControlAmount>80.00</TaxControlAmount>
    <TaxRegimeCode>TAXREG004</TaxRegimeCode>
    <Tax>10.00</Tax>
    <TaxStatusCode>TAXSTAT004</TaxStatusCode>
    <TaxJurisdictionCodeTaxJurisdictionCode>TAXJUR004</TaxJurisdictionCodeTaxJurisdictionCode>
    <TaxRateCode>TAXRATE004</TaxRateCode>
    <TaxRate>12.5%</TaxRate>
    <WithholdingTaxGroup>WTG004</WithholdingTaxGroup>
  </Detail>
</ns0:InvoiceCanonical>
```

I expect the stored procedure to successfully loop through each invoice in the XML document, extract the necessary attributes, and insert them into the respective SQL Server tables. The XQuery namespace should be correctly recognized to avoid the error mentioned above.

Hi Yitzhak,
Please find the modified code according to your suggestion.

```
USE [IntegrationStaging]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertEDIInboundInvoiceNew]    Script Date: 8/9/2023 11:15:34 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertEDIInboundInvoiceNew]
    @InvoiceStatus VARCHAR(50),
    @ProcessStatus VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @IntegrationProcess VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @InvoiceXML XML,
    @StatusMessage VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    

        DECLARE @InvoiceID VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @BusinessUnit VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @InvoiceNumber VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @InvoiceAmount VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @InvoiceDate DATE
        DECLARE @SupplierName VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @SupplierNumber VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @SupplierSite VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @InvoiceCurrency VARCHAR(10)
        DECLARE @PaymentCurrency VARCHAR(10)
        DECLARE @ImportSet VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @InvoiceType VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @LegalEntity VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @PaymentTerm VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @TermsDate DATE
        DECLARE @GoodsReceivedDate DATE
        DECLARE @InvoiceReceiveDate DATE
        DECLARE @AccountingDate DATE
        DECLARE @PaymentMethod VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @PayGroup VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @LiabilityDistribution VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @CreationDate DATETIME
        DECLARE @Source VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @IntegrationName VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @Status VARCHAR(50)

        DECLARE @LineNumber INT
        DECLARE @LineType VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @Amount VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @InvoiceQuantity INT
        DECLARE @UnitPrice VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @UOM VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @Description VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @PONumber VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @DistributionCombination VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @DistributionSet VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @TaxControlAmount VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @TaxRegimeCode VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @Tax VARCHAR(100)
        DECLARE @TaxStatusCode VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @TaxJurisdictionCode VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @TaxRateCode VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @TaxRate VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @WithholdingTaxGroup VARCHAR(50)
                -- Iterate through each invoice in the XML
        DECLARE @InvoiceNodes XML
        SET @InvoiceNodes = @InvoiceXML.query('declare namespace ns0="http://Invoice.Common.Schemas.InvoiceCanonical";
            /ns0:InvoiceCanonical')

        DECLARE @InvoiceCount INT
        
        SELECT @InvoiceCount = @InvoiceNodes.value('declare namespace ns0="http://Invoice.Common.Schemas.InvoiceCanonical";
            count(/ns0:InvoiceCanonical)', 'INT')


        DECLARE @CurrentInvoice INT = 1

        WHILE @CurrentInvoice <= @InvoiceCount
        BEGIN
            WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://Invoice.Common.Schemas.InvoiceCanonical' AS ns0)
            SELECT
                @InvoiceID = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:InvoiceID)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @BusinessUnit = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:BusinessUnit)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @InvoiceNumber = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:InvoiceNumber)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @InvoiceAmount = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:InvoiceAmount)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                @InvoiceDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:InvoiceDate)[1]', 'DATE'),
                @SupplierName = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:SupplierName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                @SupplierNumber = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:SupplierNumber)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @SupplierSite = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:SupplierSite)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @InvoiceCurrency = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:InvoiceCurrency)[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'),
                @PaymentCurrency = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:PaymentCurrency)[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'),
                @ImportSet = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:ImportSet)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @InvoiceType = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:InvoiceType)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @LegalEntity = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:LegalEntity)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @PaymentTerm = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:PaymentTerm)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @TermsDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:TermsDate)[1]', 'DATE'),
                @GoodsReceivedDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:GoodsReceivedDate)[1]', 'DATE'),
                @InvoiceReceiveDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:InvoiceReceiveDate)[1]', 'DATE'),
                @AccountingDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:AccountingDate)[1]', 'DATE'),
                @PaymentMethod = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:PaymentMethod)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @PayGroup = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:PayGroup)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @LiabilityDistribution = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:LiabilityDistribution)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @CreationDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:CreationDate)[1]', 'DATETIME'),
                @Source = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:Source)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @IntegrationName = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:IntegrationName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                @Status = InvoiceHeader.value('(ns0:Status)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
            FROM @InvoiceXML.nodes('/ns0:InvoiceCanonical[sql:variable("@CurrentInvoice")]/ns0:Header') AS InvoiceHeader(InvoiceHeader)

            -- Insert data into EDIInboundInvoiceHeader
            INSERT INTO EDIInboundInvoiceHeader (
                InvoiceStatus, ProcessStatus, IntegrationProcess, InvoiceID, BusinessUnit, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceAmount, InvoiceDate,
                SupplierName, SupplierNumber, SupplierSite, InvoiceCurrency,
                PaymentCurrency, ImportSet, InvoiceType, LegalEntity,
                CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber, PaymentTerm, TermsDate,
                GoodsReceivedDate, InvoiceReceiveDate, AccountingDate,
                PaymentMethod, PayGroup, LiabilityDistribution, CreationDate,
                Source, IntegrationName, Status
            )
            VALUES (
                @InvoiceStatus, @ProcessStatus, @IntegrationProcess, @InvoiceID, @BusinessUnit, @InvoiceNumber, @InvoiceAmount, @InvoiceDate,
                @SupplierName, @SupplierNumber, @SupplierSite, @InvoiceCurrency,
                @PaymentCurrency, @ImportSet, @InvoiceType, @LegalEntity,
                @CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber, @PaymentTerm, @TermsDate,
                @GoodsReceivedDate, @InvoiceReceiveDate, @AccountingDate,
                @PaymentMethod, @PayGroup, @LiabilityDistribution, @CreationDate,
                @Source, @IntegrationName, @Status
            )

            DECLARE @InvoiceHeaderID INT
            SET @InvoiceHeaderID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

            -- Insert data into EDIInboundInvoiceLineItems
            INSERT INTO EDIInboundInvoiceLineItems (InvoiceHeaderID, LineNumber, LineType, Amount, InvoiceQuantity, UnitPrice, UOM, Description, PONumber, DistributionCombination, DistributionSet, AccountingDate, TaxControlAmount, TaxRegimeCode, Tax, TaxStatusCode, TaxJurisdictionCodeTaxJurisdictionCode, TaxRateCode, TaxRate, WithholdingTaxGroup)
            
            SELECT
                @InvoiceHeaderID,
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:LineNumber)[1]', 'INT'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:LineType)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                -- ... other attribute extractions ...
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:Amount)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:InvoiceQuantity)[1]', 'INT'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:UnitPrice)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:UOM)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:Description)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:PONumber)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:DistributionCombination)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:DistributionSet)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:AccountingDate)[1]', 'DATE'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:TaxControlAmount)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:TaxRegimeCode)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:Tax)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:TaxStatusCode)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:TaxJurisdictionCode)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:TaxRateCode)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:TaxRate)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
                InvoiceItem.value('(ns0:WithholdingTaxGroup)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
            FROM @InvoiceXML.nodes('/ns0:InvoiceCanonical[sql:variable("@CurrentInvoice")]/ns0:Detail') AS InvoiceItem(InvoiceItem)

            SET @CurrentInvoice = @CurrentInvoice + 1
        END

        SET @StatusMessage = 'Success' -- Output message on success
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @StatusMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE() -- Return error message on failure
    END CATCH
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare namespaces before you can query XML with them.

Check it out a simplified version.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.EDIInboundInvoiceLineItems;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.EDIInboundInvoiceHeader;

CREATE TABLE dbo.EDIInboundInvoiceHeader (
    InvoiceHeaderID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    InvoiceID VARCHAR(20),
    BusinessUnit VARCHAR(20),
    InvoiceNumber VARCHAR(20)
);
CREATE TABLE dbo.EDIInboundInvoiceLineItems (
    InvoiceHeaderID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.EDIInboundInvoiceHeader(InvoiceHeaderID), 
    LineNumber INT, 
    LineType VARCHAR(20), 
    Amount MONEY, 
    InvoiceQuantity INT
);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @InvoiceXML XML =
N'<ns0:InvoiceCanonical xmlns:ns0="namespace_URL">
    <Header xmlns:ns0="namespace_URL">
        <InvoiceID>INV0001</InvoiceID>
        <BusinessUnit>BU123</BusinessUnit>
        <InvoiceNumber>INV123456</InvoiceNumber>
        <InvoiceAmount>1500.00</InvoiceAmount>
        <InvoiceDate>2023-08-01</InvoiceDate>
        <SupplierName>ABC Supplier</SupplierName>
        <SupplierNumber>SUP001</SupplierNumber>
        <SupplierSite>Main Site</SupplierSite>
        <InvoiceCurrency>USD</InvoiceCurrency>
        <PaymentCurrency>USD</PaymentCurrency>
        <ImportSet>ImportSet_123</ImportSet>
        <InvoiceType>Regular</InvoiceType>
        <LegalEntity>LE001</LegalEntity>
        <CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber>1234567890</CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber>
        <PaymentTerm>Net 30</PaymentTerm>
        <TermsDate>2023-09-01</TermsDate>
        <GoodsReceivedDate>2023-07-25</GoodsReceivedDate>
        <InvoiceReceiveDate>2023-08-02</InvoiceReceiveDate>
        <AccountingDate>2023-08-02</AccountingDate>
        <PaymentMethod>Bank Transfer</PaymentMethod>
        <PayGroup>PG001</PayGroup>
        <LiabilityDistribution>LD001</LiabilityDistribution>
        <CreationDate>2023-08-01T08:00:00</CreationDate>
        <Source>System A</Source>
        <IntegrationName>Integration_ABC</IntegrationName>
        <Status>Approved</Status>
    </Header>
    <Detail xmlns:ns0="namespace_URL">
        <InvoiceID>INV0001</InvoiceID>
        <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        <LineType>Item</LineType>
        <Amount>500.00</Amount>
        <InvoiceQuantity>10</InvoiceQuantity>
        <UnitPrice>50.00</UnitPrice>
        <UOM>EA</UOM>
        <Description>Product A</Description>
        <PONumber>PO1234</PONumber>
        <DistributionCombination>DC123</DistributionCombination>
        <DistributionSet>DS001</DistributionSet>
        <AccountingDate>2023-08-02</AccountingDate>
        <TaxControlAmount>50.00</TaxControlAmount>
        <TaxRegimeCode>TAXREG001</TaxRegimeCode>
        <Tax>10.00</Tax>
        <TaxStatusCode>TAXSTAT001</TaxStatusCode>
        <TaxJurisdictionCodeTaxJurisdictionCode>TAXJUR001</TaxJurisdictionCodeTaxJurisdictionCode>
        <TaxRateCode>TAXRATE001</TaxRateCode>
        <TaxRate>10%</TaxRate>
        <WithholdingTaxGroup>WTG001</WithholdingTaxGroup>
    </Detail>
    <Detail xmlns:ns0="namespace_URL">
        <InvoiceID>INV0001</InvoiceID>
        <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
        <LineType>Item</LineType>
        <Amount>800.00</Amount>
        <InvoiceQuantity>5</InvoiceQuantity>
        <UnitPrice>160.00</UnitPrice>
        <UOM>EA</UOM>
        <Description>Product B</Description>
        <PONumber>PO5678</PONumber>
        <DistributionCombination>DC456</DistributionCombination>
        <DistributionSet>DS002</DistributionSet>
        <AccountingDate>2023-08-03</AccountingDate>
        <TaxControlAmount>80.00</TaxControlAmount>
        <TaxRegimeCode>TAXREG002</TaxRegimeCode>
        <Tax>16.00</Tax>
        <TaxStatusCode>TAXSTAT002</TaxStatusCode>
        <TaxJurisdictionCodeTaxJurisdictionCode>TAXJUR002</TaxJurisdictionCodeTaxJurisdictionCode>
        <TaxRateCode>TAXRATE002</TaxRateCode>
        <TaxRate>20%</TaxRate>
        <WithholdingTaxGroup>WTG002</WithholdingTaxGroup>
    </Detail>
    <Detail xmlns:ns0="namespace_URL">
        <InvoiceID>INV0001</InvoiceID>
        <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
        <LineType>Item</LineType>
        <Amount>300.00</Amount>
        <InvoiceQuantity>3</InvoiceQuantity>
        <UnitPrice>100.00</UnitPrice>
        <UOM>EA</UOM>
        <Description>Product C</Description>
        <PONumber>PO9090</PONumber>
        <DistributionCombination>DC789</DistributionCombination>
        <DistributionSet>DS003</DistributionSet>
        <AccountingDate>2023-08-03</AccountingDate>
        <TaxControlAmount>30.00</TaxControlAmount>
        <TaxRegimeCode>TAXREG003</TaxRegimeCode>
        <Tax>9.00</Tax>
        <TaxStatusCode>TAXSTAT003</TaxStatusCode>
        <TaxJurisdictionCodeTaxJurisdictionCode>TAXJUR003</TaxJurisdictionCodeTaxJurisdictionCode>
        <TaxRateCode>TAXRATE003</TaxRateCode>
        <TaxRate>9%</TaxRate>
        <WithholdingTaxGroup>WTG003</WithholdingTaxGroup>
    </Detail>
</ns0:InvoiceCanonical>
<ns0:InvoiceCanonical xmlns:ns0="namespace_URL">
  <Header xmlns:ns0="http://Invoice.Common.Schemas.InvoiceCanonical">
    <InvoiceID>INV0002</InvoiceID>
    <BusinessUnit>BU456</BusinessUnit>
    <InvoiceNumber>INV789012</InvoiceNumber>
    <InvoiceAmount>2500.00</InvoiceAmount>
    <InvoiceDate>2023-08-05</InvoiceDate>
    <SupplierName>XYZ Suppliers</SupplierName>
    <SupplierNumber>SUP002</SupplierNumber>
    <SupplierSite>Secondary Site</SupplierSite>
    <InvoiceCurrency>EUR</InvoiceCurrency>
    <PaymentCurrency>EUR</PaymentCurrency>
    <ImportSet>ImportSet_456</ImportSet>
    <InvoiceType>Special</InvoiceType>
    <LegalEntity>LE002</LegalEntity>
    <CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber>9876543210</CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber>
    <PaymentTerm>Net 45</PaymentTerm>
    <TermsDate>2023-09-15</TermsDate>
    <GoodsReceivedDate>2023-08-01</GoodsReceivedDate>
    <InvoiceReceiveDate>2023-08-06</InvoiceReceiveDate>
    <AccountingDate>2023-08-06</AccountingDate>
    <PaymentMethod>Credit Card</PaymentMethod>
    <PayGroup>PG002</PayGroup>
    <LiabilityDistribution>LD002</LiabilityDistribution>
    <CreationDate>2023-08-05T09:30:00</CreationDate>
    <Source>System B</Source>
    <IntegrationName>Integration_XYZ</IntegrationName>
    <Status>Pending Approval</Status>
  </Header>
  <Detail xmlns:ns0="namespace_URL">
    <InvoiceID>INV0002</InvoiceID>
    <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
    <LineType>Item</LineType>
    <Amount>800.00</Amount>
    <InvoiceQuantity>8</InvoiceQuantity>
    <UnitPrice>100.00</UnitPrice>
    <UOM>EA</UOM>
    <Description>Product X</Description>
    <PONumber>PO9876</PONumber>
    <DistributionCombination>DC987</DistributionCombination>
    <DistributionSet>DS004</DistributionSet>
    <AccountingDate>2023-08-06</AccountingDate>
    <TaxControlAmount>80.00</TaxControlAmount>
    <TaxRegimeCode>TAXREG004</TaxRegimeCode>
    <Tax>10.00</Tax>
    <TaxStatusCode>TAXSTAT004</TaxStatusCode>
    <TaxJurisdictionCodeTaxJurisdictionCode>TAXJUR004</TaxJurisdictionCodeTaxJurisdictionCode>
    <TaxRateCode>TAXRATE004</TaxRateCode>
    <TaxRate>12.5%</TaxRate>
    <WithholdingTaxGroup>WTG004</WithholdingTaxGroup>
  </Detail>
</ns0:InvoiceCanonical>';

DECLARE @InvoiceCount INT = (
    SELECT @InvoiceXML.value('declare namespace ns0="namespace_URL";
        count(/ns0:InvoiceCanonical)', 'INT'));

DECLARE @InvoiceHeaderID INT
    , @CurrentInvoice INT = 1;

WHILE @CurrentInvoice <= @InvoiceCount 
BEGIN
    -- Insert data into EDIInboundInvoiceHeader table
    WITH XMLNAMESPACES('namespace_URL' AS ns0)
    INSERT INTO dbo.EDIInboundInvoiceHeader (InvoiceID, BusinessUnit, InvoiceNumber )
    SELECT InvoiceHeader.value('(InvoiceID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
        , InvoiceHeader.value('(BusinessUnit/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
        , InvoiceHeader.value('(InvoiceNumber/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
        -- add the rest of the XML elements
    FROM @InvoiceXML.nodes('/ns0:InvoiceCanonical[sql:variable("@CurrentInvoice")]/Header') AS InvoiceHeader(InvoiceHeader);

    SET @InvoiceHeaderID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    -- Insert data into EDIInboundInvoiceLineItems table
    WITH XMLNAMESPACES('namespace_URL' AS ns0)
    INSERT INTO dbo.EDIInboundInvoiceLineItems (InvoiceHeaderID, LineNumber, LineType, Amount, InvoiceQuantity)
    SELECT @InvoiceHeaderID
        , InvoiceItem.value('(LineNumber/text())[1]', 'INT')
        , InvoiceItem.value('(LineType/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
        , InvoiceItem.value('(Amount/text())[1]', 'MONEY')
        , InvoiceItem.value('(InvoiceQuantity/text())[1]', 'INT')
        -- add the rest of the XML elements
    FROM @InvoiceXML.nodes('/ns0:InvoiceCanonical[sql:variable("@CurrentInvoice")]/Detail') AS InvoiceItem(InvoiceItem);

    SET @CurrentInvoice += 1;
END;

-- test
SELECT * FROM dbo.EDIInboundInvoiceHeader;
SELECT * FROM dbo.EDIInboundInvoiceLineItems;
```

**EDIInboundInvoiceHeader**

| InvoiceHeaderID | InvoiceID | BusinessUnit | InvoiceNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | INV0001 | BU123 | INV123456 |
| 2 | INV0002 | BU456 | INV789012 |

**EDIInboundInvoiceLineItems**

| InvoiceHeaderID | LineNumber | LineType | Amount | InvoiceQuantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Item | 500.00 | 10 |
| 1 | 2 | Item | 800.00 | 5 |
| 1 | 3 | Item | 300.00 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | Item | 800.00 | 8 |

Comment: Hi Yitzhak, I tried this but I am getting the same error: Msg 2229, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertEDIInboundInvoiceNew, Line 150 [Batch Start Line 8]
XQuery [nodes()]: The name "ns0" does not denote a namespace.

Comment: You have two levels: *InvoiceHeader* and *InvoiceLineItems*. So, you need to apply fixes that I showed  on both levels.

Comment: Hi Yitzhak, I made the changes at both levels.:        WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://Invoice.Common.Schemas.InvoiceCanonical' AS ns0)
FROM @InvoiceXML.nodes('/ns0:InvoiceCanonical[sql:variable("@CurrentInvoice")]/ns0:Header') AS InvoiceHeader(InvoiceHeader)
FROM @InvoiceXML.nodes('/ns0:InvoiceCanonical[sql:variable("@CurrentInvoice")]/ns0:Detail') AS InvoiceItem(InvoiceItem)

Comment: Please add your T-SQL with the fixes to the original question.

Comment: Hi @YitzhakKhabinsky, I have added the modified code in the original question

Comment: I updated the answer. Please give it a shot.

Comment: Hi @Yitzhak, I am able to execute the stored procedure now with your updated code. However, only the [EDIInboundInvoiceHeader] table is updated partially with InvoiceHeaderID, InvoiceStatus,ProcessStatus,IntegrationProcess. Rest of the fields are updated as null which should not be the case.

No records were inserted in [dbo].[EDIInboundInvoiceLineItems]

Comment: Please add to your original question both CREATE TABLE ... statements, and all the SP input parameters values.

Comment: It's only the root node which needs the namespace

Comment: @VipinJayanarayanan, I provided an answer following  a **minimal reproducible example** pattern. You copy it to SSMS as-is, run it, and it is working.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, The new code is working fine. Thank you very much. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you need to specify the namespace in a `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`. But it's only the first node `InvoiceCanonical` which needs it specified, the others are in the empty namespace.

- You can further improve this code massively, by instead of using the cursor you just `OUTPUT inserted.InvoiceHeaderID INTO @tableVariable`, then correlate back in another `INSERT` query.
- You also don't need a separate `SELECT`, as you can do another `OUTPUT` to select everything back to the client.
- Don't use that horrible `TRY CATCH` instead just allow errors to bubble back to the client properly.
- Use `/text()` for better performance in your XQuery.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertEDIInboundInvoiceNew]
    @InvoiceStatus VARCHAR(50),
    @ProcessStatus VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @IntegrationProcess VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @InvoiceXML XML
AS

DECLARE @ids TABLE (InvoiceID varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY, InvoiceHeaderID int not null);

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
    'namespace_URL' AS ns0
)
INSERT INTO EDIInboundInvoiceHeader (
  InvoiceStatus, ProcessStatus, IntegrationProcess, InvoiceID, BusinessUnit, InvoiceNumber, InvoiceAmount, InvoiceDate,
  SupplierName, SupplierNumber, SupplierSite, InvoiceCurrency,
  PaymentCurrency, ImportSet, InvoiceType, LegalEntity,
  CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber, PaymentTerm, TermsDate,
  GoodsReceivedDate, InvoiceReceiveDate, AccountingDate,
  PaymentMethod, PayGroup, LiabilityDistribution, CreationDate,
  Source, IntegrationName, Status
)

OUTPUT inserted.InvoiceID, inserted.InvoiceHeaderID INTO @ids (InvoiceID, InvoiceHeaderID)
OUTPUT inserted.*

SELECT
  @InvoiceStatus,
  @ProcessStatus,
  @IntegrationProcess,
  InvoiceID = InvoiceHeader.value('(InvoiceID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  BusinessUnit = InvoiceHeader.value('(BusinessUnit/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  InvoiceNumber = InvoiceHeader.value('(InvoiceNumber/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  InvoiceAmount = InvoiceHeader.value('(InvoiceAmount/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
  InvoiceDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(InvoiceDate/text())[1]', 'DATE'),
  SupplierName = InvoiceHeader.value('(SupplierName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
  SupplierNumber = InvoiceHeader.value('(SupplierNumber/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  SupplierSite = InvoiceHeader.value('(SupplierSite/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  InvoiceCurrency = InvoiceHeader.value('(InvoiceCurrency/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'),
  PaymentCurrency = InvoiceHeader.value('(PaymentCurrency/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)'),
  ImportSet = InvoiceHeader.value('(ImportSet/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  InvoiceType = InvoiceHeader.value('(InvoiceType/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  LegalEntity = InvoiceHeader.value('(LegalEntity/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber = InvoiceHeader.value('(CustomerTaxRegistrationNumber/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  PaymentTerm = InvoiceHeader.value('(PaymentTerm/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  TermsDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(TermsDate/text())[1]', 'DATE'),
  GoodsReceivedDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(GoodsReceivedDate/text())[1]', 'DATE'),
  InvoiceReceiveDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(InvoiceReceiveDate/text())[1]', 'DATE'),
  AccountingDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(AccountingDate/text())[1]', 'DATE'),
  PaymentMethod = InvoiceHeader.value('(PaymentMethod/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  PayGroup = InvoiceHeader.value('(PayGroup/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  LiabilityDistribution = InvoiceHeader.value('(LiabilityDistribution/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  CreationDate = InvoiceHeader.value('(CreationDate/text())[1]', 'DATETIME'),
  Source = InvoiceHeader.value('(Source/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  IntegrationName = InvoiceHeader.value('(IntegrationName/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  Status = InvoiceHeader.value('(Status/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
FROM @InvoiceXML.nodes('/ns0:InvoiceCanonical/Header') AS InvoiceHeader(InvoiceHeader);


WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
    'namespace_URL' AS ns0
)
INSERT INTO EDIInboundInvoiceLineItems (
    InvoiceHeaderID, LineNumber, LineType, Amount, InvoiceQuantity, UnitPrice, UOM, Description,
    PONumber, DistributionCombination, DistributionSet, AccountingDate, TaxControlAmount, TaxRegimeCode,
    Tax, TaxStatusCode, TaxJurisdictionCode, TaxRateCode, TaxRate, WithholdingTaxGroup
)
SELECT
  ids.InvoiceHeaderID,
  InvoiceItem.value('(LineNumber/text())[1]', 'INT'),
  InvoiceItem.value('(LineType/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  -- ... other attribute extractions ...
  InvoiceItem.value('(Amount/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
  InvoiceItem.value('(InvoiceQuantity/text())[1]', 'INT'),
  InvoiceItem.value('(UnitPrice/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
  InvoiceItem.value('(UOM/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  InvoiceItem.value('(Description/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
  InvoiceItem.value('(PONumber/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  InvoiceItem.value('(DistributionCombination/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  InvoiceItem.value('(DistributionSet/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  InvoiceItem.value('(AccountingDate/text())[1]', 'DATE'),
  InvoiceItem.value('(TaxControlAmount/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
  InvoiceItem.value('(TaxRegimeCode/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  InvoiceItem.value('(Tax/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)'),
  InvoiceItem.value('(TaxStatusCode/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  InvoiceItem.value('(TaxJurisdictionCode/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  InvoiceItem.value('(TaxRateCode/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  InvoiceItem.value('(TaxRate/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
  InvoiceItem.value('(WithholdingTaxGroup/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
FROM @InvoiceXML.nodes('/ns0:InvoiceCanonical/Detail') AS InvoiceItem(InvoiceItem)
JOIN @ids ids ON ids.InvoiceID = InvoiceItem.value('(InvoiceID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)');
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/EVOLWrSx)

Comment: Hi @Charlieface, I tried running this stored procedure which you shared with default namespace. It did not insert any records.

Comment: Just realized it was only the root node which needed the namespace, see edit. Also see fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/EVOLWrSx